# Change CSV name to CSV date time python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I want to change csv name (in this case Example.csv) to a specific name: date time name. I have a library called `from datetime import datetime`

This is my sentence to create a cvsFile:

```
with open('Example.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
```

I want that my output to be:

```
20180820.csv
20180821.csv
20180822.csv ... etc
```

And if I run more that one time in the same day, I want that my output to be:

```
20180820.csv (First time that I run the script) 
20180821(2).csv (Second time run) 
... etc
```

Comment: You should just use the correct string instead of 'Example.csv' (what did you try up to now? What's your issue?). Please note that IMHO using parenthesis in filename should be avoided.

Comment: OK, I'll take into account your opinion of avoiding parentheses in file names. In this case, if I execute the code more than once, how can I differentiate the names?

Comment: @AnnaCastan You can add seconds or even milliseconds into the filename.

Comment: By the way, a filename format in the form of %Y%m%d instead of %d%m%Y (i.e. 20180820 instead of 20082018) has the added benefit that if the filenames are sorted alphabetically, they are sorted chronologically as well.

Comment: @blhsing OK, this it will be better than put parenthesis. Thank you.

Comment: @Odysseas Oh sorry, I was a mistake writing the question. In my code (as you can see below) It is correctly placed like year + month + day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Only take the real time in a variable, and then concatenate with .csv (and also I put this csv output in a specific folder called output). Finally I open the csvFile with the variable name.

```
> now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%Hh%M')
> csvname = './output/' + now + '.csv'
> with open(csvname, 'w') as csvFile:
```

> I can not do the second part of my problem. I want that if I run more than one time the code the date time name change or add (2), (3)... etc.

Comment: try using the solution i provided. it should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = str(current_date.day)+str(current_date.month)+str(current_date.year)
df.to_csv(str(filename + '.csv'))
```

Comment: Perfect, but I prefer not use pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know how to create the file name you just have to check whether it already exists or not :

```
def exists(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            file_exists = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        file_exists = False
    return file_exists

name = 'some_date.csv'
c = 0
while exists(filename):
    c += 1
    name = 'some_date({}).csv'.format(c)

# do stuff with name
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find a solution if you can manage a 'progressive' variable taking track of the files. Otherwise you need to check the disk content and it might be rather more complex.

```
import datetime
progressive = 0

today = datetime.date.today()
todaystr = str(today)

rootname = todaystr
progressive += 1
if progressive > 1:
    rootname = todaystr + '_' + str(progressive)

filename = rootname + '.csv'
```

Comment: This will give you the same name when ever you run the code wont it?

Comment: @Lorenzo  When I debug the code, cannot find the reference .today().

Comment: @Radan I think that the variable progressive it is like a count. This count is put next to de filename with _ this symbol.

Comment: sorry @AnnaCastan its a count i agree, but count of what? its not count anything.

Comment: Hi @Radan I specified in the text that 'progressive' should be the counter of the files you already created, and the app should manage to keep the counter updated, otherwise your solution counting the files is needed.

Comment: if it is a long running process, it should reset everyday? i was under the impression its a periodic script. idk.

Comment: @AnnaCastan did you try the solution i gave? it will help you count the number of files in the folder, this solution is good but, does not solve your problem because when you run the code again variable "progressive" will be re-initialized.

Comment: Yes @Radan is right. My solution could be ok only if you keep track of 'progressive' in a text file. But in that case, there would be the risk of getting that text file out of sync with the actual disk content. So try that solution!

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of files in the directory with the same date in its name and use that information to create the file name. Here is a solution for both your problems.

```
import datetime
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d")
# count the number of files already in the output dir with date (now)
count = len([name for name in os.listdir('./output/') if (os.path.isfile(name) and now in name)])

csv_name = './output/' + now 

if count > 0:
    csv_name = csv_name + "(" + str(count+1) +")"

csv_name = csv_name + ".csv"

with open(csv_name, 'w') as csvFile:
    pass
```

Good Luck.